# ResponsiveSlides.js full screen background images

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using ResponsiveSlides.js which i got working great but what i really want to do is to have the slide images as background images so that i can make the slides fit the full width and height of the viewport.

The page and documentation i followed are here-
http://responsiveslides.com/

You will see that ordinarily, the slide images are basically image tags placed within list items in the html.. But in order to get those images to fill the browser window, as i understand it, they need to become background images which i have successfully done before on other sites.

However, after much research i found this from the author of the plugin-
https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/issues/113

Here, the author explains that in order to achieve what i'm trying to do myself, then the html should use empty list items or divs to specify the background image using css. I have tried doing this and the images do not appear at all.. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ResponsiveSlides you can try to set the ul style to

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1; /*To make sure it does not cover anything */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

But it seems that the plugin wasn't made for this. You should consider using a different plugin, such as http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try your suggestion. After looking again at the plugin i'm using i did think i should look for another solution until i found the authors comment stating that it is doable (found on the link i included above). This gave me hope that i could get it to work the way i wanted since i love everything else about it.. i will try your suggestion in any case